# getopt() function exhibiting weird behaviour

Tags: c, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, getopt, command-line-tool

Adding getopt() for option arguments to an already existing program results in weird behaviour.

The program takes a string input then reads words from a file(each on a new line) and checks if the string is in the file.If it is, the string is sent to an Existing.txt file and if not, it goes to Non-existing.txt.
The problem is with getopt() and the weird behaviour it exhibits.(The options are -n and -e to change the Non-existing and existing files respectively)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    char word[80];
    char word_in_file[80];
    int ch;


FILE *existing = fopen("Existing.txt", "w");      //Open the existing and non_existing file streams   
FILE *non_existing = fopen("Non-existent.txt", "w");

    while((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "n:e:")) != -1){
    switch(ch){
        case 'n':     
            non_existing = fopen(optarg, "w");
            break;

        case 'e':               
            existing = fopen(optarg, "w");
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr,"Unknown option argument: %s", optarg);
            return 1;
    }
        argc -= optind;
        argv += optind;
}

printf("Enter ZA WARDSU:\n");
while (scanf("%79s[^\n]", &word)) { //Main loop that scans input 
    if(strcmp(word ,"exit") == 0){
        printf("You are now done!\n");
        break;
    }
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // The stream is initialised here in order to reset it for every loop, the next loop just begins from where it last cut off

    while ((fscanf(input, "%79s[^\n]\n", &word_in_file) != EOF)) { // loop that scans the input file 
        if(strcmp(word_in_file, word) == 0 ){                       //if word is in the input file, print it to the existing file 
            fprintf(existing, "%s\n", word);    
            break;  

        }              

    }
    if (strcmp(word, word_in_file) != 0 )       //if word isn't in the input file, print it to the non_existing file 
        fprintf(non_existing, "%s\n", word);    //In main loop because it needs to do this check after it's gone through all the words

}   

fclose(existing);      //close some data streams
fclose(non_existing);
return 0; 
}
```

So whenever I start it like that - `./check -n Nexname.txt -e Exname.txt inFile.txt` it just segfaults and the stackdump is something like `Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=001801C189A`

Then I try - `./check -nNexname.txt -eExname.txt inFile.txt`.This time it doesn't crash, but it only makes and writes to the first option's argument file, and for the second it just writes to the default.

And if I try to do it with only one option like that - `./check -nNexname.txt  inFile.txt` it just stops the program after I write in the first word.

Edit: It also doesn't segfault when I do it like that `./check -n Nexname.txt -eExname.txt inFile.txt`

Can somebody please explain to me the reason for this behaviour(and how to fix it).

I know I can just use the main function args to do the same thing, but I wanted to try out the getopt() function, in order to get familiar with it.

Comment: To solve crashes you should first of all use a debugger to locate where in your code they happen. And when you catch the crash and go to your code, then you should examine variables to make sure their values seem okay and valid.

Comment: I think your code would be easier to test if you only try to open each file once. That is, look at your command line options and decide whether to override the default filenames, and **then** try to open the files. But make sure that the files are open before you try writing to them.

Comment: Also, never use `argv[x]` (for any `x`) directly without making sure that it's valid. After `getopt`, are you sure `argv[1]` is valid and not a null pointer?

Comment: And of course, you don't check for errors. What if one of the `fopen` calls fails? And taking about `fopen`, you can leak files, as you unconditionally open the files `existing` and `non_existing` before parsing options.

Comment: `while (scanf("%79s[^\n]", &word))` is at least three bugs.

Comment: @melpomene I'm pretty much sure the whole problem is in the getopt() and the options. The program runs fine with the default settings, and when I was making it I used the main function args to choose file names and it worked perfectly.
So can you point out the 3 bugs in that partucular line ?

Comment: @skygear: 1) `scanf` returns EOF (-1) if it hits the end of the input stream. That's a true value so your while loop will never terminate. 2) `[^\n]` is just a sequence of literal characters. If you want the character class, then you need a `%` but if you add a `%` you'll need to provide another argument so you probably meant `%*[^\n]`, although that is still not perfect.

Comment: 3): `&word` is a pointer to a `char[80]`, but `scanf` wants a pointer to the first thing in a character array; that is a pointer to a `char`. It's probably OK in this case but it is UB and it will break horribly if you someday decide `word` shoukd be dynamically allocated. Use `word` instead.

Comment: @rici I don't really understand the 2-nd one(so far I've only been taught [^\n] makes scanf() read  the whole line, mind that I'm still a beginner).
The 1-st one however is supposed to be that way. The first loop is infinite. You type `exit` to break from it and stop the program.
The second loop scans the whole file and breaks if it finds the word. If not the loop ends and checks if the last word isn't equal to the one you entered.If it isn't it sends it to non-existing.
Then the whole thing repeats again and again until you say you want to exit, that's the whole point.

Comment: @Skygear: once scanf reports eof, it will always reort eof without trying to read anything. So the program will just hang. That cannot be correct behaviour. Ask your teacher if you don't believe me.

Comment: @skygear: and w.r.t. the second point, `scanf("%9[^\n]", word);` matches from one to nine characters, stopping at the first newline and copies them into `word`, or fails if the next character is a newline. `scanf("%*[^\n]");` skips input until a newline is found, and does not save them (because of the `*`). `scanf("[^\n]");` (without the percent) matches up to four characters, which must be precisely `[`, `^`, `\n` and `]`, in that order; it stops early if it hits a non-matching character. If you didn't notice this, it's because you never tested with a very long input.

Answer (score 2):

If you indented that code better, it would be clear that you are modifying `argv` and `argc` inside the `while` loop instead of doing that once after all options have been handled.

Answer (score 0):

Create char arrays for the default file names.
Set the FILE pointers to NULL.
Copy the command options into the char arrays.
Check for duplicate file names.
Open the files.
Scan a word from stdin.
Scan words from the input file, trying to find a match.
After the input file has been read, rewind it for the next word from stdin.
Close all the files.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void useage ( char *name);

int main ( int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char non_existing_file[80] = "Non-existent.txt";//default file name
    char existing_file[80] = "Existing.txt";
    char input_file[80] = "Default.txt";
    char word[80] = "";
    char word_in_file[80] = "";
    int ch = 0;
    //do not open files. Could be argument or default
    FILE *existing = NULL;
    FILE *non_existing = NULL;
    FILE *input = NULL;

    opterr = 0;//suppress default error messages

    while ( ( ch = getopt ( argc, argv, "n:e:")) != -1) {
        switch ( ch) {
            case 'n':
                if ( optarg) {//optarg not NULL
                    strncpy ( non_existing_file, optarg, 79);
                    non_existing_file[79] = 0;//make sure zero terminated
                }
                break;
            case 'e':
                if ( optarg) {
                    strncpy ( existing_file, optarg, 79);
                    existing_file[79] = 0;
                }
                break;
            case '?':
                if ( optopt == 'e' || optopt == 'n') {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
                }
                else {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "\ninvalid option -%c\n", optopt);
                }
            default:
                useage ( argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }
    }

    if ( ! strcmp ( non_existing_file, existing_file)) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "\nduplicate file names for options -e and -n\n");
        useage ( argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    if ( optind < argc) {//another argument to process
        if ( ! strcmp ( non_existing_file, argv[optind])
        || ! strcmp ( argv[optind], existing_file)) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "\ninput file name matches file name for options -e or -n\n");
            useage ( argv[0]);
            return 1;
        }
        strncpy ( input_file, argv[optind], 79);
        input_file[79] = 0;
    }

    //open files

    if ( NULL == ( input = fopen ( input_file, "r"))) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "could not open %s\n", input_file);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf ( "%s opened\n", input_file);
    }

    if ( NULL == ( existing = fopen ( existing_file, "w"))) {
        fclose ( input);//close the already opened
        fprintf ( stderr, "could not open %s\n", existing_file);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf ( "opened %s\n", existing_file);
    }

    if ( NULL == ( non_existing = fopen( non_existing_file, "w"))) {
        fclose ( input);//close the already opened
        fclose ( existing);
        fprintf ( stderr, "could not open %s\n", non_existing_file);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf ( "opened %s\n", non_existing_file);
    }

    int found = 0;
    printf ( "Enter ZA WARDSU:\n");
    while ( 1 == scanf ( "%79s", word)) { //Main loop that scans stdin
        if ( strcmp ( word , "exit") == 0) {
            printf ( "You are now done!\n");
            break;
        }
        found = 0;
        while ( 1 == fscanf ( input, "%79s", word_in_file)) { // loop that scans the input file
            if ( strcmp ( word_in_file, word) == 0 ) {//if word is in the input file, print it to the existing file
                fprintf ( existing, "%s\n", word);
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( ! found) {//if word isn't in the input file, print it to the non_existing file
            fprintf ( non_existing, "%s\n", word);//In main loop because it needs to do this check after it's gone through all the words
        }
        rewind ( input);//back to start of input to check for next word
    }

    fclose ( existing);
    fclose ( non_existing);
    fclose ( input);
    return 0;
}

void useage ( char *name) {
    fprintf(stderr
    , "\nUsage:\n\t%s [-eopte] [-noptn] [opt]\n or\n\t%s [-e opte] [-n optn] [opt]\n"
    , name, name);
}
```